# How to remove a particular element from a stack?

Tags: java, stack

I'm trying to accept an input of the element to be removed and pop all those from the stack.

```
String[] colors={"Red","Green","White","Yellow","Blue"};
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
Stack<String> stack=new Stack<String>();

void push(){
        System.out.println("Stack after all the elements are pushed is");

        for(int i=0; i<12; ++i){
            //defining a random element to be pushed into the stack
            int rnd=new Random().nextInt(colors.length);
            //pushing the element into the stack
            stack.push(colors[rnd]);
            if(i>11)
                break;
            //displaying all the elements present in the stack. 
            System.out.println(stack.get(i));
        }

}

void pop(String str){
    System.out.println("Enter the Color to be removed");

    while(!stack.empty()) {

        System.out.println("Element removed is "+stack.pop());

    }   


}
```

main program

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws StackOverflowError {
    StackExample obj=new StackExample();
    obj.push();
    obj.display();

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    String s= sc.next();
    obj.pop(s);
    obj.display();
}
```

Comment: A stack is not the right data-structure for that. Try using a list instead.
If you really want to use a stack you will have to pop all elements and only push those back that you want to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will go out on a limb here and try to answer your question. I do not get the point of an array of colors here. Neither do I get the point of using a stack. I'll use the stack since that is what you asked for.

*It looks like a homework question. So, instead of writing out the solution for you, I will try to point you in the right direction.*

Lets say you have an array of String that contain the inputted colors.

`String[] colors = {"Black", "Green", "Blue", "Black"};`

The stack you will be using is declared as:
`Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();`

Let's input all the colors into this stack:

```
for(String color: colors)
    stack.push(color);
```

Stack works in a last-in-first-out manner. Say we have to remove `"Black"` from the stack. After this operation, the stack should look like this: `["Blue", "Green"]`. One approach to do this is to use an auxiliary stack to store all the elements we want to keep and discard ones we don't need.

```
String compareString = "Black";
Stack<String> auxStack = new Stack<String>();
while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
    String st = stack.pop();
    if(st.compareTo(compareString) != 0)
        auxStack.push(st);
}

while(!auxStack.isEmpty()) 
    stack.push(auxStack.pop());
```

This should point you towards the right direction. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I was actually supposed to do this in CPP but i wanted to try it in java too.